# Use an input-box instead of putting the credentials in code

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell

I have made a script that I would distribute to my college's. It's a Powershell script using CSOM to connect to a SharePoint-Online environment. What I would like is to create an input box where my college's can enter their credentials.
Because now I have put my userid en password in the code itself. How can I change the CSOM code to create an inputbox? I know that the command: “$credential = get-credential” generates a inputbox too. How can I change the code below that a user can logon through an inputbox.

```
$SiteUrl = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
$UserName="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
$Password ="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
$Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($UserName,(ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force))
$Context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteUrl) 
$Context.Credentials = $credentials
```

Gr, P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code:

```
$SiteUrl = "https://company.sharepoint.com"
$Credentials = Get-Credential

$Context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteUrl) 
$Context.Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($Credentials.UserName,$Credentials.Password)
```

or this:

```
$SiteUrl = "https://company.sharepoint.com"
$UserName = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter username"
$SecurePassword = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter password" -AsSecureString

$Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($UserName,$SecurePassword)
$Context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteUrl) 
$Context.Credentials = $Credentials
```

if you have enabled 2FA you need to use something like [THIS](https://www.mavention.nl/blogs-cat/using-mfa-enabled-accounts-in-powershell-scripts/?cn-reloaded=1).

Comment: Both doesn't work

Comment: edited, working for me now

Comment: I get error: "Exception calling "ExecuteQuery" with "0" argument(s): "The partner returned a bad sign-in name or password error. For more information, see Federation Error-handling Scenarios."

Comment: Have you set Modern authentization? This could be a problem, cause you need to pop-up the new login window? or 2FA authentication?

Comment: I have read your link to 2FA and found the solution. Thx. P

Comment: Great, you're welcome :)