# powershell edit user profile field with MFA

Tags: powershell, user-profile, online

I have several scripts to edit user profile fields through Powershell without active MFA. 
Sure I can have a user with a complex password outside MFA but I don't want that.
Can anyone point me to one script that works with MFA? 
It's a sharepoint online system.
Thanks a lot
Nuno

Answer (score 0):

I takled about in [this question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/256622/use-an-input-box-instead-of-putting-the-credentials-in-code/256624#256624). If you need to use MFA authentication, just use [this manual for login.](https://www.mavention.nl/blogs-cat/using-mfa-enabled-accounts-in-powershell-scripts/?cn-reloaded=1)

Use this code:

```
if ( $MFA ) {
    Login-AzureRmAccount
    Connect-SPOService -Url $urlSPOAdmin
}
```

*Hope it helps!*